# Getting errors 50290,91 and 424 in MS Access 2010 when closing Excel workbook

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a VBA module that opens an Excel workbook and copies data from an Access query to the cells in the Excel workbook. Everything works, until I close the Excel workbook. When that happens I get errors 50290, 91, and 424. These errors seem to occur randomly and the line of code where the module crashes is never the same. It appears to crash at random places.

Here is the first part of the module where everything is defined:

```
Dim RecSet As DAO.Recordset
Dim objXLAppln As Excel.Application
Dim objWBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim StrPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim strBrowseMsg As String, strInitialDirectory As String, strFilter As String
'show dialogue box
strBrowseMsg = "Select the EXCEL file:"
'set directory to load files from
strInitialDirectory = "C:\Bridge_CIP_Part-A_B\"
'run strFilter function
strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "Excel Files (*.xlsx)", "*.xlsx")
StrPathFile = ahtCommonFileOpenSave(InitialDir:=strInitialDirectory, _
   Filter:=strFilter, OpenFile:=True, _
   DialogTitle:=strBrowseMsg, _
   Flags:=ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY)
If StrPathFile = "" Then
   MsgBox "No file was selected.", vbOK, "No Selection"
   Exit Function
End If
'Set Excel application object. Critical for macro to run properly. Do not change.
Set objXLAppln = New Excel.Application
'Open workbook and worksheet to load data.
With objXLAppln
    Set objWBook = .Workbooks.Open(StrPathFile)
    objXLAppln.Visible = True
End With
Set RecSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Part_A-B Query")
```

Here is the code block at the end where I close everything:

```
'Close everything
RecSet.Close
objWBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
objXLAppln.Quit
Set RecSet = Nothing
Set objWBook = Nothing
Set objXLAppln = Nothing
```

How do I get the code to close the workbook without crashing?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show which lines are the random errors, I take a general stance where several issues can be the cause:

**Reference Library** - There could be a missing or unknown library reference. Check Alt+F11/Tools/References on every computer that runs the Access application. Also, since you run [Early Binding](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115), be sure all machines that run this database has the Excel library object selected with correct version. Alternatively, late binding `Set objXLAppln = CreateObject('Excel.Application')` can avoid this reference compatibility across machines.

**Different Windows OS (Windows 7 vs 8 vs 8.1, 32-bit vs. 64-bit)** Instead of the standard Windows open file dialog, consider using the [Application.FileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196794.aspx) which proves to be more stable across OS.

```
Dim fd As Object

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
    .Title = "Select the EXCEL file:"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel files (*.xlsx)", "*.xlsx"
    .FilterIndex = 1
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Bridge_CIP_Part-A_B\"
    If .Show = True Then
        strFilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        'The user pressed Cancel.
        MsgBox "No file Selected", vbExclamation
        Set fd = Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If
End With
```

**Manage Flow**
You open an Excel object to screen `objXLAppln.Visible = True`, output an Access query into an existing workbook but don't save it `SaveChanges:=False` and then exit `objXLAppln.Quit`. This is not quite an error but reconcile this procedure. In your error handling, close out of objects just the same:

```
On Error Goto ErrHandle:
...
ErrHandle:
   'Close everything
   Msgbox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
   RecSet.Close
   objWBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
   objXLAppln.Quit
   Set RecSet = Nothing
   Set objWBook = Nothing
   Set objXLAppln = Nothing 
   Exit Function
```

Also, be sure to check [Task Manager/Processes](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/open-task-manager) to see if older Excel.exe instances are not remaining due to prior errors; read-only files may still be in memory. Finally, after major VBA code changes and error troubleshooting, [decompile and compact](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/performance/decompile.asp) your database.

Good luck!